# Converting HTML to string with tags

Tags: html, swift, xcode

In my app I want to fetch text in HTML format from the server and convert it into string to display using UILabel in another view. To convert the HTML to string I am using this extension:

```
extension Data{
var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString?{
    do{
        return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    }catch{
        print("error", error)
        return nil
    }
}

  var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
  }
}

extension String{
   var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    return Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
  }
  var html2String: String{
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
  }
}
```

The string is called from an array like so:

```
text.detailText = textArray[0].html2String
```

However when the data is displayed onscreen the string just displays as plain text without the HTML tags. What do I need to modify in the extension to display the text properly with the tags in affect?

EDIT: the `text` label in  `text.detailText` refers to another class.

In context it looks like this:

The text variable in context refers to another class. In context it looks like this:

```
     if let otherClass = segue.destination as? otherClass {
         otherClass.detailText = textArray[0].html2String    
     }
```

The other class looks like this:

class otherClass: UIViewController {

```
var data: Data?

@IBOutlet weak var otherDetail: UILabel!

var detailText: String =  ""    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    otherDetail?.text = detailText    
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set your htmlAttributedString to label `attributedText`?

Comment: No I haven't do I set that at extension or at text.detailText?

Comment: What is the `text` variable in your context? Is it a label?

Comment: Try to pass NSAttributedString to controller and use label `attributedText` to display

Comment: `otherDetail?.text = detailText` That's clearly settings the `String` (so just "letters"), not the `NSAttributedString` (which has attributes and may have then different rendering). Instead do `otherDetails?.text = detailAttributedText`, declare `detailAttributedText` as a `NSAttributedString` and set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this simple example, it works. I just set label `attributedText` field

```
let htmlString = """
<p><b>This text is bold</b></p>
<p><i>This text is italic</i></p>
<p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p>
"""

let attributedString = htmlString.data(using: .utf8).flatMap { data -> NSAttributedString? in
    return try? NSAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ],
        documentAttributes: nil)
}
guard let attrString = attributedString else { return }
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
yourLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

Hope, this code will help you

Answer (score 0):

In order to render the html tags, you should use attributed strings:

```
 //detailText should be of type NSAttributedString
 detailedText : NSAttributedString!

 //replace html2String with html2AttributedString
 if let otherClass = segue.destination as? otherClass {
     otherClass.detailText = textArray[0].html2AttributedString    
 } 

 //and in the otherClass replace .text with .
 var data: Data?

 @IBOutlet weak var otherDetail: UILabel!

 var detailText: NSAttributedString!    
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     otherDetail?.attributedText = detailText    
 }
```